# Unable to customize legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am plotting yearly demand using `ggplot` (my code below) but I am not able to put color legend for the plot. My data.frame has "Zone" and "TotalDemand" (only 2 columns) and I have three data.frames for three years ("sales12", "sales13" and "sales14").

```
ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=sales12, aes(x=factor(Zone), y=TotalDemand/1000), 
           color='green',size=6, shape=17) +
geom_point(data=sales13, aes(x=factor(Zone), y=TotalDemand/1000), 
           color='red',size=6, shape=18)+
geom_point(data=sales14, aes(x=factor(Zone), y=TotalDemand/1000), 
           color='black',size=4, shape=19) + 
labs(y='Demand (in 1000s)',x='Zones') +
scale_colour_manual(name = 'the colour', 
                    values = c('green'='green', 'black'='black', 'red'='red'), 
                    labels = c('12','13','14'))
```

Please help me to identify my mistake.

Comment: may be my question is not clear so it has received a down vote. I have used three colors for 3 years and I am not able to put them as legend. I tried looking at the help provided on related posts before posting my question here. :)

Comment: you need not pot three times `geom_point` like that. create a variable for year and in aes you can use that to colur the points. its very basic ggplot. this shows you have not read any thing before posting this question. nonethless, if you can provide a reproducible example, you will get an answer.

Comment: If you want a legend, you must map something to color in `aes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a very small example data frame, df, I melted it to format it for `ggplot`.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Zone = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Alpha", "Baker", 
"Charlie", "Delta"), class = "factor"), TotalDemand = c(90L, 
180L, 57L, 159L), sales12 = c(25L, 40L, 13L, 50L), sales13 = c(30L, 
60L, 16L, 55L), sales14 = c(35L, 80L, 28L, 54L)), .Names = c("Zone", 
"TotalDemand", "sales12", "sales13", "sales14"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df.m <- melt(df, id.vars = "Zone", measure.vars = c("sales12", "sales13", "sales14"))

ggplot(df.m, aes(x=factor(Zone), y=value, color = variable )) + 
  geom_point(size=6, shape=17) +
  labs(y='Demand (in 1000s)',x='Zones') +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('green', 'black', 'red'))
```

You can adjust size and shape and colors of your points, add a title, etc..  Your legend can also be positioned on the bottom, for example.

[image]